# how to cancel timeout when next calling arrives in useEffect react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, settimeout

I want to clear or cancel the timeout when next calling arrives.

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    // set timeout to control unwanted searches
     setTimeout(doSearch, 300);
    return () => {
      // prevent search to call if new Search request arrives ?

    };
  }, [searchKey]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in this way to clear your previous timer

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(doSearch, 300);
    return () => {
       clearTimeout(timer)    
    };
  }, [searchKey]);
```

Comment: thanks I also found a complete guide for working with settimeout in hooks : https://upmostly.com/tutorials/settimeout-in-react-components-using-hooks